# To draw polar plot where points in order by column 1?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, polar-coordinates

Data

```
0   0.867779926444275
15  0.895866066532554
30  0.791816991652543
45  0.729582701499042
60  0.510896493274811
75  0.349659272558701
90  0.255383327300393
105 0.383729598278156
120 0.604795433670792
135 0.731177670225856
150 0.783135047098391
165 0.984715658218028
```

Code in Matlab

```
polar(data(:,1), data(:,2), 'k-');
```

which gives

[image]

You see that the first point (0) is connected to the 2nd point (135). 
I would like that points are connected in order like 0 to 15, 15 to 30, ..., 150 to 165, and eventually 165 to 0 possibly.

**How can you draw polar plot where points are connected by the order in column 1?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`polar`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polar.html) expects the first input to be **in radians**, not in degrees. So, use

```
polar(data(:,1)*pi/180, data(:,2), 'k-');
```

With your example values, this gives

[image]

To connect last point to first, just repeat the first point at the end:

```
polar(data([1:end 1],1)*pi/180, data([1:end 1],2), 'k-');
```

[image]

Comment: argh, I'm too slow! For the second question (connecting back to 0), just append the first coordinate pair.

Comment: @excaza Thanks! I was precisely adding that :-) I tend to read the questions too quickly...

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I like your way of not appending data to the original data set. It is much better to use the [1:end 1] .

Comment: @Masi Yes, that way it's automatically done, only for the plot

Comment: I opened a new thread about connecting the end points in a polarPlot here http://stackoverflow.com/q/29548121/54964 For some reason, interpolation function does not handle the extended points as other points.